# reset the chrome background color to default

Tags: google-chrome

I had used some settings/flags on google chrome to set the all page background colour to black.

current look - all the sites look like this.
[image]

I want that to reset to white default one, can someone help with this.

I followed some internet blog for this change which I totally forgot now.

note - it was not an extension from the chrome store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Dark Mode flags?
type chrome://flags into the address bar (also sometimes called the omnibox)

There is a flag Force "Dark Mode for Web Contents" Disable it